# Accessing MySQL through dynamic IP address

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on creating a MySQL database server for one of my school projects. I want to allow my teammates to access the server remotely using school network, but I discovered that their IP addresses varied whenever they reconnected to the school network, and it won't be desirable to manually add all the new IP addresses to the user table. Is there any trick I could use to overcome this problem?

Comment: If you want to permit access from an undetermined set of IP addresses while not exposing your database server to the whole internet, a VPN might be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `%` as a wildcard to summarize source nets ands limit your attack vector.

so instead of 192.168.68.34, use 192.168.68.% assuming they use a /24 address space for vpn.